# Laravel is returning invalid format after Request validation

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm starting to study Laravel 7.x and I'm getting a validation error. Running the code below I'm getting "The start is not a valid date." and "The end is not a valid date.". How can I fix it?

web.php:
`Route::post('/store-fast-event', 'fastEventsController@storeFastEvent')->name('routeStoreFastEvent');`

event.js:

```
        let id = $("#modalFastEvent input[name='id']").val();

        let title = $("#modalFastEvent input[name='title']").val();

        let start = $("#modalFastEvent input[name='start']").val();

        let end = $("#modalFastEvent input[name='end']").val();

        let color = $("#modalFastEvent input[name='color']").val();

        let FastEvent = {

            title : title,
            start : start,
            end : end,
            color : color,

        }

        route = routeFastEvents('routeStoreFastEvent');
        sendFastEventRoute(route, FastEvent);

    })
```

Request.php:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required | min:3',
            'start' => 'date:H:i:s | before:end',
            'end' => 'date:H:i:s | after:start',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'Preencha o campo Título',
            'title.min' => 'O título deve conter no mínimo 3 caracteres',
            'start.date' => 'The start is not a valid date',
            'start.before' => 'A hora inicial deve ser anterior a hora final',
            'end.date' => 'The end is not a valid date."',
            'end.after' => 'A hora final deve ser posterior a hora inicial',

        ];
    }
```

Comment: Should `date:H:i:s` be `date_format:H:i:s`?

Comment: Ty, I've already tried this and didn't work.

Comment: @michaeljdennis another idea?

Answer (score 1):

The php request is gonna pass the date in format of **Y-m-d** (check your request header). So in your validation use

```
'start' => 'date|after_or_equal:' . now()->format('jS F Y'), // accepts >= today
'end' => 'data|after:start' // accepts > start
```

Comment: That's a good point. For reservation systems. Or `now()->addDays(2)` in some cases. But we don't know really. It could be a date in the past in his app. What I do is just drop the `after` on `start`, just check the format and if the `end` is after `start`.

Comment: Ty for the answers but I'm trying to get only the time. I'm using  ```$('.time').mask('00:00:00');```